# Proving random variable being measurable respective to another variable is constant

Tags: probability-theory

An exercise on a chapter on conditional probability and expectation goes as follows:

> Suppose $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, and also X and Y are independent. Prove that there is $C \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbf{P}(Y = C) = 1$.

The exercise also gives a hint, suggesting proving that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} : \mathbf{P}(Y \leq y) = 0$ or $1$.

I'm not sure how to prove the latter either, and how to get the right intuition at which direction the proof should go. Whatever conditional expectation or probability I considered, it gave no new insights on the behavior of $Y$. So how one might solve this?

Comment: Are you sure there's not another assumption that you're leaving out?  Maybe it was stated earlier?  I could very well be missing something, and there are others here with much more insight than I have, but I don't see how the conclusion could be justified with what you've said.   Is anything said about $Y$'s cumulative distribution function, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{Y \le y\} \in \sigma(X)$ since $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable. Yet, $\sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma(X)$ are independent, so
$$P(Y \le y) = P(\{Y \le y\} \cap \{Y \le y\}) = P(Y \le y)^2.$$

Comment: This exercise is more on the idea of the proof of the Kolmogorov's Zero-One Law then! Thanks!